# sstream not populating vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, sstream

With input in the command line:

```
1 2 3
```

Which is stored in '*line*' my vector is only being populated with

```
1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code

```
string line;
    string buffer;
    int a,b,base;

    cin >> line;
    stringstream ss(line);
    std::vector<string> tokens;
    while( ss >> buffer){
        tokens.push_back(buffer);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++){cout << tokens[i] << endl;}
```

Comment: Try replacing `cin >> line;` with `std::getline(cin, line);`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
cin >> line;
```

Note that this function

```
operator>>(istream& is, string& str)
```

gets all characters until the first occurrence of whitespace (in the case of input `1 2 3`, it stops on the space after `1`)

Try using the function `getline()`, which reads the string up until the first occurrence of a newline.

This seems to work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string line;
    string buffer;
    int a,b,base;

    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector<string> tokens;
    while( ss >> buffer){
        tokens.push_back(buffer);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++){cout << tokens[i] << endl;}

    return 0;
}
```